# Error: Declaration of non-variable 'strlen' in 'for' loop initial declaration - C

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors, c99, strlen

The title is the exact error my compiler(geany on ubuntu) gives me when I try to compile. The part of code in question is the following:

```
for(int q=strlen(stringA)-1;q>0;q--)
{
//do stuff
}
```

I've already set the C99 mode and the initialization of variables in the 'for' header is accepted. Is what I did simply illegal in C?

Comment: Missing `#include <string.h>`?  (BTW, why use type `int`?)

Comment: Ok, that really got me because I used strlen a lot of times in the same code but the compiler only gave me "warnings". Now it works.

Comment: You mean that I should use short? Sure, that's an optimization that I had in mind, but I usually optimize this kind of things(non logic related) in the end.

Comment: This [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) shows what is returned by: `size_t strlen(const char *str);`

Comment: ...but `size_t` is an `unsigned` data type, so a loop that tests `q >= 0` would be infinite. However you don't do that - for some reason with `q > 0` you don't want the zeroth element.

Comment: Yes, an `unsigned` variable is always `>= 0 `

Comment: I see what you mean, I did indeed delete my previous comment after 1.5 seconds. You were supposing what would happen if I declared 'q' as size_t.

Comment: Consider `for(size_t q=strlen(stringA); q-- > 0; ) { stuff }`  `size_t` is the Goldilocks type for indexing and size.  not too wide, not too narrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are missing an include. Try:

`#include <string.h>`

Comment: I didn't notice it was missing for the reason I wrote in the comment area of my question. Thanks.